Select SQL statement on same column
I want to select distinct count(id) as activeusers from a table where useractive=1, but at the same time I want to select all the users example distinct Count(id) as totalusers regardless of activestate. How to achieve this in a SQL query?

Hello, you want to query twice the same table, so you need to use a joined query. Select count(table1.id) as totalusers, count(table2.id) from mytable table1, mytable table2 where table2.useractive = 1
There are other prettier solutions

Please tag the RDBMS you use

You could call count over a case expression:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE useractive WHEN 1 THEN id END) AS active_users,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS total_users
FROM   mytable

